# I forgot my admin password

Tags: forgot-your-password

I forgot the way I spelled the answer to my first security question, and keep getting blocked (now for 24 hours!) since I was forced to change my password this morning.

Can I authenticate some other way?

Comment: You can always reset your passowrd ?

Comment: But how? I forgot also the way i spelled the answer to the security question! :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reset instantly, contact customer care through phone.

Administrators - you can reset passwords using the steps in our "Reset Passwords for your Users" help documentation.

If you're the only Administrator and you can't access your login, create a case with Salesforce Customer Support and request to reset your password (please include your username in your case details).

Create a case with Salesforce Customer Support online
Contact Salesforce Customer Support via phone

Link - [Source](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005251&language=en_US)

Comment: Not always possible if you are a solo admin, but it is good practice to have 2 administrators in any 1 org as it means that the other admin can reset your password if you are locked out.

Comment: is there any way to reset password if you are solo admin apart from calling customer care executive ?

Comment: As a solo admin you can use the normal reset password functions as long as you remember your security question, otherwise you are forced to go to SF Customer Care.

Comment: Yes, but in this case security question has forgotton.